# Infinity as an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can infinity be an element of a set? For example:

{$1,2, \infty,4$}

I understand $\infty$ is not a real number

Comment: "A set" can contain anything. {1,2,Elephant,4} is a set.

Comment: @billpg: it's not quite as simple: you do need to properly define what you mean by the things you list as set elements. A slight distortion of your example shows this very clearly: if $\{1,2,\text{Elephant},4\}$ is a set, what is $\{1,2,\text{Elephant},4,\text{Elephant}\}$? It would certainly also be a set, but it's totally not clear whether it would contain two different elephants, or rather the _value_ $\text{Elephant}$, whose redundant appeareance in the set-builder doesn't make any difference. Similarly, $\{1,\infty\}$ doesn't make sense if $\infty$ was never defined as such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're talking about as a subset of real numbers, no.  If you're talking about an arbitrary set,  then sure, as long as you define what you mean by $\infty$.  For instance,  you could mean it as the one point added in the one point compactification of the real numbers, then it certainly can be an element of a set

Answer (score 6):

$\infty $ is indeed not a real number. However, sets don't have to only have real numbers as elements. So, if you want, you can add the symbol $\infty $ to any set you like. You can define the meaning of $\infty $ in various ways too.

Answer (score 2):

As a relevant side remark: An interesting treatment of $\infty$ is the one point compactification, for example the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{P}^1\sim \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty \}$. This could also be done on $\mathbb{R}$ by considering $S^1$ projecting onto $\mathbb{R}$. You can google one point compactification for details.